# How to solve ValueError when testing truth value of Dataframe contents? Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, valueerror

I have a Dataframe that looks like this.

```
   done    sentence                        3_tags
0  0       ['What', 'were', 'the', '...]   ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT']
1  0       ['What', 'was', 'the', '...]    ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT']
2  0       ['Why', 'did', 'John', '...]    ['WP', 'VBD', 'NN']
...
```

For each row I want to check if the list in column '*3_tags*' is on a list temp1, as follows:

```
a = pd.read_csv('sentences.csv')
temp1 = [ ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT'], ['WRB', 'JJ', 'VBZ'], ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT'] ]
q = a['3_tags'] 
q in temp1
```

For the first sentence in row 0, the value of '*3_tags*' = ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT'] which is in temp1 so I expect the result of the above to be:

```
True
```

However, I get this error:

> ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 1 vs 3

I suspect that there is some problem with the datatype of q:

```
print(type(q))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Is the problem that q is a Series and temp1 contains lists? What should I do to get the logical result 'True' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want those lists to be tuples instead.
Then use `pd.Series.isin`

```
*temp1, = map(tuple, temp1)

q = a['3_tags'].apply(tuple)

q.isin(temp1)

0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: 3_tags, dtype: bool
```

---

However, it appears that the `'3_tags'` column consists of strings that look like lists.  In this case, we want to parse them with `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

*temp1, = map(tuple, temp1)

q = a['3_tags'].apply(lambda x: tuple(literal_eval(x)))

q.isin(temp1)

0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: 3_tags, dtype: bool
```

---

**Setup1**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'done': [0, 0, 0],
    'sentence': list(map(str.split, ('What were the', 'What was the', 'Why did John'))),
    '3_tags': list(map(str.split, ('WP VBD DT', 'WP VBD DT', 'WP VBD NN')))
}, columns='done sentence 3_tags'.split())

temp1 = [['WP', 'VBD', 'DT'], ['WRB', 'JJ', 'VBZ'], ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT']]
```

**Setup2**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'done': [0, 0, 0],
    'sentence': list(map(str.split, ('What were the', 'What was the', 'Why did John'))),
    '3_tags': list(map(str, map(str.split, ('WP VBD DT', 'WP VBD DT', 'WP VBD NN'))))
}, columns='done sentence 3_tags'.split())

temp1 = [['WP', 'VBD', 'DT'], ['WRB', 'JJ', 'VBZ'], ['WP', 'VBD', 'DT']]
```

Comment: In the Setup, I do not understand how to prepare my (very large) DataFrame the way you show. How do I convert it to tuples?

Comment: The setup is to produce the variables `a` and `temp1` as you had them.  You shouldn't have to do anything.  That is for others who may want to test it out.  You just need to use the code in the top portion.

Comment: Thanks, got it. When I use the top portion it gives another error:     ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Comment: When I do q = a['3_tags'].apply(tuple) and then print(q), I get: ([, ', D, T, ', ,,  , ', N, N, ', ,,  , ', I, ...

Comment: That means your data frame is all messed up.  In your post it looks like those elements in `'3_tags'` are lists when they are strings that look like lists.  I'll update my post to account for that.  In fact, if you are able, you should provide a method to reproduce exactly what your data is.

Comment: I am confused myself. I also thought that my data in '3_tags' are lists - which is want I want them to be. But they appear to be strings, so I have done something wrong when creating the '3_tags' column. I am afraid I cannot reproduce exactly what my data is.

Comment: The line q.isin(temp1) still throws the ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2). I am afraid I need to fix my data first.

Comment: Read [mcve] thats what we expect to make this process easier.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, at least I now know my data is a mess.

Comment: No problem.  I've been there myself.

Comment: I have tried to describe the method by which the data was created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580996/how-to-deal-with-lists-becoming-strings-after-saving-to-csv-and-re-opening-pyth